# Template class T

Tags: c++, template-classes

If I have

```
template<class T> class Vector

public:
   Vector(const Vector& bla);
```

How can I use it outside the .h file?

I´ve tried `Vector<T>::Vector` but that doesn´t work.

some part of the .h file

```
           Vector();

    Vector(int size, T value = T());

    Vector(const Vector& vec);

    ~Vector();

    T at(int index) const;

    void set_value_at(int index, T elem) const;
```

);
       //Here is the code in same .h file but outside the class

```
   Vector();

    Vector(int size, T value = T())
            {}

    Vector(const Vector& vec){}

    ~Vector(){}

    T at(int index) const{}

    void set_value_at(int index, T elem) const{}
```

Comment: Please be more clear. Show the entire `.h` file, as well as where/how you're trying to use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to **implement** `Vector()`, you do it like this:

```
template<class T> Vector<T>::Vector(const Vector<T>& bla)
{
    ...
}
```

If you are trying to **use** `Vector()`, you do it like this:

```
Vector<SomeTypeHere> vec1;
Vector<SomeTypeHere> vec2(vec1);
```

Comment: If I use it on this function:
    template<class T>Vector<T>::Vector(int size, T value = T())

I get this error: error: default argument given for parameter 2 of'Vector<T>::Vector(int, T)'

Comment: Default parameter values can only be specified in the **declaration**, not in the **implementation**, eg: `template <class T> Vector { public: Vector(int size, T value = T()); };` `template <class T> Vector<T>::Vector(int size, T value) {...}`, unless they are inlined together (which is most common when using templates), eg: `template <class T> Vector { public : Vector(int size, T value = T()) { ... } };`

Answer (score 0):

If you did everything right, `Vector<type> v(args)` should automatically call what looks like the constructor. To use other functions:

```
v.myFunc();
```

Static functions:

```
Vector<type>::mystaticfunc();
```